# Serialize dataclass with class as a field to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, nested, python-dataclasses

At a project I'm contributing to we have a very simple, but important class (let's call it `LegacyClass`). Modifying it would be a long process.
I'm contributing new dataclasses (like `NormalDataclass`) to this project and I need to be able to serialize them to JSON.
I don't have access to the JSON encoder, so I cannot specify custom encoder.

Here you can find sample code

```py
import dataclasses
import collections
import json

#region I cannot easily change this code
class LegacyClass(collections.abc.Iterable):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    
    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.a
        yield self.b
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"({self.a}, {self.b})"
#endregion

#region I can do whatever I want to this part of code
@dataclasses.dataclass
class NormalDataclass:
    legacy_class: LegacyClass


legacy_class = LegacyClass('a', 'b')
normal_dataclass = NormalDataclass(legacy_class)

normal_dataclass_dict = dataclasses.asdict(normal_dataclass)
#endregion

#region I cannot easily change this code
json.dumps(normal_dataclass_dict)
#endregion
```

What I would want to get:

```json
{"legacy_class": {"a": "a", "b": "b"}}
```

What I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Object of type LegacyClass is not JSON serializable
```

Do you have any suggestions?
Specifying `dict_factory` as an argument to `dataclasses.asdict` would be an option, if there would not be multiple levels of `LegacyClass` nesting, eg:

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass
class AnotherNormalDataclass:
    custom_class: List[Tuple[int, LegacyClass]]
```

To make `dict_factory` recursive would be to basically rewrite `dataclasses.asdict` implementation.

Comment: what's wrong with passing `default` argument to `json.dumps`? *Edit*: check out my answer

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** The simplest solution, based on the most recent edit to the question above, would be to define your own `dict()` method which returns a JSON-serializable `dict` object. Though in the long term,  I'd probably suggest contacting the team who implements the `json.dumps` part, to see if they can update the encoder implementation for the dataclass.

In any case, here's a working example you can use for the present scenario:

```py
import dataclasses
import collections
import json


class LegacyClass(collections.abc.Iterable):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.a
        yield self.b

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"({self.a}, {self.b})"


@dataclasses.dataclass
class NormalDataclass:
    legacy_class: LegacyClass

    def dict(self):
        return {'legacy_class': self.legacy_class.__dict__}


legacy_class = LegacyClass('a', 'b')
normal_dataclass = NormalDataclass(legacy_class)

normal_dataclass_dict = normal_dataclass.dict()
print(normal_dataclass_dict)
json.dumps(normal_dataclass_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'legacy_class': {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}}
```

---

You should be able to pass `default` argument to `json.dumps`, which will be called whenever the encoder finds an object that it can't serialize to JSON, for example a Python class or a `datetime` object.

For example:

```py
import dataclasses
import collections
import json


class LegacyClass(collections.abc.Iterable):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.a
        yield self.b

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"({self.a}, {self.b})"


@dataclasses.dataclass
class NormalDataclass:
    legacy_class: LegacyClass


legacy_class = LegacyClass('aa', 'bb')
normal_dataclass = NormalDataclass(legacy_class)

normal_dataclass_dict = dataclasses.asdict(normal_dataclass)


o = json.dumps(normal_dataclass_dict,
               ### ADDED ###
               default=lambda o: o.__dict__)

print(o)  # {"legacy_class": {"a": "aa", "b": "bb"}}
```

---

If you have a more complex use case, you could consider creating a default function which can check the type of each value as it gets serialized to JSON:

```py
import dataclasses
import collections
import json
from datetime import date, time
from typing import Any


class LegacyClass(collections.abc.Iterable):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.a
        yield self.b

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"({self.a}, {self.b})"


@dataclasses.dataclass
class NormalDataclass:
    legacy_class: LegacyClass
    my_date: date = date.min


legacy_class = LegacyClass('aa', 'bb')
normal_dataclass = NormalDataclass(legacy_class)

normal_dataclass_dict = dataclasses.asdict(normal_dataclass)


def default_func(o: Any):

    # it's a date, time, or datetime
    if isinstance(o, (date, time)):
        return o.isoformat()

    # it's a Python class (with a `__dict__` attribute)
    if isinstance(type(o), type) and hasattr(o, '__dict__'):
        return o.__dict__

    # print a warning and return a null
    print(f'couldn\'t find an encoder for: {o!r}, type={type(o)}')
    return None


o = json.dumps(normal_dataclass_dict, default=default_func)

print(o)  # {"legacy_class": {"a": "aa", "b": "bb"}, "my_date": "0001-01-01"}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I've edited my post to make clearer, that I do not have easy access to ```json.dumps``` part. I'm sending ```dict``` to module that does it. If no ideas come regarding creating ```dict``` made up of python primitives (instead of ```LegacyClass```, probably I would have to ask the team responsible for that module to include sth like this.

Comment: @dreptak ah I see, thanks for clarifying a bit better. I updated my post above with a current workaround you can use for the present. It involves defining your own logic for serializing the `NormalDataclass` object, and using `__dict__` to retrieve a valid `dict` representation of the `LegacyClass` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a third-party dependency, you can solve the problem with [mashumaro](https://github.com/Fatal1ty/mashumaro). You just need to add DataClassDictMixin and register a custom serialization / deserialization method for LegacyClass:

```
from mashumaro import DataClassDictMixin
from mashumaro.config import BaseConfig

@dataclasses.dataclass
class NormalDataclass(DataClassDictMixin):
    legacy_class: LegacyClass

    class Config(BaseConfig):
        serialization_strategy = {
            LegacyClass: {
                "serialize": lambda x: {"a": x.a, "b": x.b},
                "deserialize": lambda d: LegacyClass(d["a"], d["b"]),
            }
        }


legacy_class = LegacyClass('a', 'b')
normal_dataclass = NormalDataclass(legacy_class)

normal_dataclass_dict = normal_dataclass.to_dict()
print(normal_dataclass_dict)
s = json.dumps(normal_dataclass_dict)
print(s)
```